# No version of Android SDK Build-Tools installed

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools, build-tools

My Gradle project sync is failing in Android Studio and it is showing the following errors:

[Gradle project sync failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iF9Gt.png)

[Failed to find target with hash string 'android-26' in: C\Users\...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDP2r.png)

To fix this I tried to install android API 26 but when I did I realized that no version of the Android SDK Build-Tools was installed:

[SDK Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDdgh.png)

When trying to update the Build-Tools through the SDK manager I got the following error:

To install:
- Android SDK Build-Tools 27.0.1 (build-tools;27.0.1)
Preparing "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 27.0.1 (revision: 27.0.1)".
Failed packages:
- Android SDK Build-Tools 27.0.1 (build-tools;27.0.1)

Does anyone have any advice on how to get past this issue?

Comment: Check your proxy setting.

Comment: Right now it's set to no proxy, how should it be?

Comment: Why are you trying to update the build tools first? You don't have to do this in order to install the android-26 platform. And the screenshot you provided shows you already have some build tools - just not the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

you're missing platform `android-26` which must be placed in subfolder platform of `SDK`. Download `android-26.zip` from Google repository and extract it to the said path above. Clean & Rebuild your project.